How do you protect the salt in Cordova vue?
I have an app made on view, it generates crypto wallet addresses. The user from can retrieve them with a mnemonic phrase. Clearly, I encrypt all this with standard methods, mnemonic phrase + password + user pincode. But I also want to add the salt of the application that works offline.
The question is: am I doing it right? Can you take a look at my code and tell me if this is correct from a security point of view or if I need to do something else?
Thats my code:
import BIP32Factory from 'bip32';
import * as ecc from 'tiny-secp256k1';
import * as bitcoin from 'bitcoinjs-lib';
import * as bip39 from "bip39"
import * as ethUtil from '@ethereumjs/util';
import { hexlify } from 'ethers'; // v5.5.4
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const salt = "ajwhdvwt7awtd7awvhdawvdjadytadavwGAJDhagwkdjVAwndbvawmdnfawd65a4wd65awdfawhdkvakjwbvdvi76ar654354hgvnbvnbvasnbdvansbvdavwdmvawdnbvawdvawdawtd67awd5a7wiuydgajwhdawd76r4^$#^%&$*&^%^&UIGUWAGJKDWHVADA%^WD$A^&%wfidgahwvdakbwdabwnvdatywudra567wda43$%&EAWUGHDVAWDVAWJD"


function encryptMnemonic(mnemonic, password) {
    const passphrase = password + salt; 
    const encryptedMnemonic = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(mnemonic, passphrase).toString();
    return encryptedMnemonic;
}

function decryptMnemonic(encryptedMnemonic, password) {
    const passphrase = password + salt;
    const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedMnemonic, passphrase);
    const originalMnemonic = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return originalMnemonic;
}


export default function useCrypto() {

  const createKey = (pincode, password) => {
    if(!pincode || !password) return {
      success: false,
      error: "174"
    }

    const bip32 = BIP32Factory(ecc);
    const seedPhrase = bip39.generateMnemonic(256);

    const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(seedPhrase);

    // For Ethereum
    const ETH_DERIVATION_PATH = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/0";
    const ethNode = bip32.fromSeed(seed).derivePath(ETH_DERIVATION_PATH);
    const tvt = ethUtil.privateToAddress(ethNode.privateKey)
    const ethAddress = hexlify(tvt); 

    // For Bitcoin
    const BTC_DERIVATION_PATH = "m/44'/0'/0'/0/0";
    const btcNode = bip32.fromSeed(seed).derivePath(BTC_DERIVATION_PATH);
    const { address } = bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: btcNode.publicKey });

    const encrypted = encryptMnemonic(seedPhrase, pincode, password);

    return {
      success: true,
      key: encrypted,
      btc: address,
      eth: ethAddress,
      seed: seedPhrase
    }
  }

  return { createKey }
}




Clearly stackoverflow is not a good place to ask for security advice. Hire a professional consultant if you are very serious about that. In the meantime read some white papers for the basics of it and add some hardware keys for the user (using webauthn for example) + store them safely on your side.

A salt/key on the client is exposed to everyone.
You can migrate this logic to a backend server utilizing express or use Nuxt as your server to handle it on the backend with proper env variable that is hidden form the end user.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
